# About binding record to gridview from 2 tables in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have one gridview. I have one table(source) that contains fields like sourceid, name and another table(target) that contains fields like targetid, from, to,date.
In that target table from & to fields are ids refer to source table's sourceid's.
So i have to bind record of target table i.e to bind fields :
from - here name should come respect to that source id from source table
to - here name should come respect to that source id from source table
date should come from target table.

How i can do this?
Asp.net c#

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to perform a SQL inner join referencing the SourceTable twice -- once for the [From] column and once for [To] -- to output the columns you want into a single resultset.

```
SELECT t.targetid, t.[date], s1.[name] as [from], s2.[name] as [to]
FROM TargetTable t
INNER JOIN SourceTable s1
    ON t.from = s1.sourceid
INNER JOIN SourceTable s2
    ON t.to = s2.sourceid
```

Comment: if i have to bind this data to gridview through dataset then how i can do this? i did but its giving error. my code is as follows:'DataSet ds31 = new DataSet(); SqlDataAdapter da31 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT t.targetid, t.[date], s1.[name] as [from], s2.[name] as [to] FROM TargetTable t INNER JOIN SourceTable s1 ON t.from = s1.sourceid INNER JOIN SourceTable s2 ON t.to = s2.sourceid",FLYCON); da31.Fill(ds31); { mygridview.DataSource = ds31; mygridview.DataBind(); }'

Comment: Do you need to replace 'SourceTable' and 'TargetTable' with your actual table names?